# osu installer restarts all the time wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

When I try to install osu! with wine the installer goes too 100% and then restarts in an endless loop. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` first. if that doesn't work then try [this](https://gitlab.com/Espionage724/Linux/blob/master/Scripts/osu.sh)  script